# Disable automatic redirect to https iis

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, https

I have a problem to solve and despite my efforts I haven't found a solution.

I have a project running on IIS and not using the default ports 80 and 443 for http and https. These ports are used by another environment running on the same machine. I use 8080 and 44307.

But on this environment I have a problem, when I try to access a page via http with port 8080 in the url, I am automatically redirected to https and port 44307.

I don't have a Rewrite URL configured so I don't understand this redirection. This creates several problems at the project level and I would like to have solutions.

Comment: do you use PLESK ?

Comment: @Aristos No, is it a host ? In my case, the IIS are hosted by my own company.

Comment: Plesk is a helper program... anyway, open the IIS, go to the site, and check the ISAPI Filters, and the other settings... check also your web.config

Comment: Follow up those 30x redirection responses in FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis and easily you know where they come from.

Comment: Do you use code to redirect to https? You can check if there is a redirect code in your global.asax file.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered here : https://serverfault.com/questions/502048/iis-7-0-unwanted-automatic-redirect-to-https

IIS don't do that kind of redirection without an extra configuration. It's your app that is doing that.

I tested it on IIS 8, with ASP.Net Core. When I removed `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` from the Configure method inside `Startup.cs`, the redirecting stopped, and I could access my site over HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Probably very late answer but it might help , there is also a setting on iis on advance setting under hsts it can be set to false to prevent redirect, another way it seems,
[image]

after that restart your IIS (just in case) and clear the cache memory from your browser.